# get a string between each / within string

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have column Values that needs to be splited after every \ occurrence.
I need to fetch each word within each occurrence of \ and create new columns.
[image]
How do I do this in pyspark (databricks)? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From your input, I am considering this is your DataFrame:

```
+------+------+------+---------------------+
|FieldA|FieldB|FieldC|Values               |
+------+------+------+---------------------+
|1     |a     |hello |\abc\def\ghi\jk-l\mno|
|2     |b     |you   |\I\like\to\Code      |
|3     |b     |there |\Th-at\works         |
+------+------+------+---------------------+
```

1. Replace all the unwanted characters from the `values` column with `|`

```
df = df \
.withColumn("Values", regexp_replace("Values", "\\\\", "|")) \
.withColumn("Values", regexp_replace("Values", "\\a", "|a")) \
.withColumn("Values", regexp_replace("Values", "\\t", "|t")) \
.withColumn("Values", regexp_replace("Values", "\\s", "|s")) \
.withColumn("Values", regexp_replace("Values", "\\n", "|n"))
```

2. Now split the column values using the specified delimiter `|`

```
df = df.withColumn("Values", split("Values", "\|"))
```

3. Extract the records into array format

```
records = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect()
```

4. In-order to insert records of varying column, the data has to be sent as key value pair

```
output_records=[]
for record in records:
    values = record["Values"]
    words = [value for value in values if len(value)>0]
    
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        column_name, column_values = f"col_{i+1}", word
        if record.get(column_name, None) is None:
            record[column_name] = word
        
    del record["Values"]
    output_records.append(record)
```

This is how `output_records` looks like:

```
[
{'FieldA': 1, 'FieldB': 'a', 'FieldC': 'hello', 'col_1': 'abc', 'col_2': 'def', 'col_3': 'ghi', 'col_4': 'jk-l', 'col_5': 'mno'},
{'FieldA': 2, 'FieldB': 'b', 'FieldC': 'you', 'col_1': 'I', 'col_2': 'like', 'col_3': 'to', 'col_4': 'Code'},
{'FieldA': 3, 'FieldB': 'b', 'FieldC': 'there', 'col_1': 'Th-at', 'col_2': 'works'}
]
```

5. Now create a Spark DataFrame using this `output_records`

```
spark.createDataFrame(output_records).show()
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|FieldA|FieldB|FieldC|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|
+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     1|     a| hello|  abc|  def|  ghi| jk-l|  mno|
|     2|     b|   you|    I| like|   to| Code| null|
|     3|     b| there|Th-at|works| null| null| null|
+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have another few columns in original df as well along with this values column, I am having trouble to integrate them. at the end in the output, it should have all the rest of df fields as is and values should split thru (col1 till col5)

Comment: Some of value fields have - in it

Comment: Hi, as per your new requirement I have updated the answer. If it helps you, please mark it as answer :)

Comment: it failed at last step 5 with error : Some of types cannot be determined after inferring. I try to display records (step 3) it gives the same error. I have lot of column (about 100), not sure if that is issue. It works If I just pick 2-3 columns.

Comment: Just forgot to change variable name, try now.

Comment: Code is same and same error. What change you want me to make?

Comment: change the variable name from output_data to output_records

Comment: If you can provide the complete dataset we can see what problems we are getting

Comment: I have changed that variable already. Its big file, not sure if I can post that here and sensitive data we well.

Comment: What I can do is create new fields from that just field, create df and then join back to original data df.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


from pyspark.sql.functions import split

data = [(1, 'a', 'hello', r'\abc\def\ghi\jk-l\mno'),
        (2, 'b', 'you', r'\I\like\to\Code'),
        (3, 'b', 'there', r'\Th-at\works')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['FieldA', 'FieldB', 'FieldC', 'Values'])

# Split the column, remove the blanks, create dynamic columns based on the array

df = df.withColumn('split_col',F.split(col('Values'),r'\\'))
df = df.withColumn("split_array", array_remove(df["split_col"], ""))
df = df.withColumn('cnt', F.size('split_array'))

max = df.agg(F.max('cnt')).first()[0]

textcols = [F.col('split_array')[i].alias(f'col{i+1}') for i in range(0, max)]

df.select([F.col('FieldA'),F.col('FieldB'),F.col('FieldC')] + textcols).show()
```

Check the sample output below:
[image]